After switching change page the dark mode toggle is not functioning
I have a small problem I have a theme switch button that turn the page to dark mode, but if I am in the home page and change to contact page the theme switch stops working, but this happens only on the other pages except the main one, and I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to mess around with the js code, but nothing.
Here is my JavaScript code:
// DarkMode
let darkmode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode")
const themeSwitch = document.getElementById("theme-switch")

const enableDarkmode = () => {
    document.body.classList.add("darkmode")
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", "active")
    document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-white.png"
}

const disableDarkmode = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("darkmode")
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", null)
    document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-blue.png";
}

if (darkmode ==="active") enableDarkmode()

themeSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => {
    darkmode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode")

    darkmode !== "active" ? enableDarkmode() : disableDarkmode()
})


Does this code, and the theme-switch element, exist in all pages?

I have trouble understanding, your question mixes the concepts of darkmode and color theme... To determine if a browser is in darkmode use : window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

How are you testing this? Using local files directly, or via a web server? localStorage will not work with local files, you need to be using a web server. If you are using a web server, and it is publicly accessible, please edit your post to include a link to your site ... that will help us to help you.

Yes the theme-switch element exist in al pages

Im kinda new with js but I think I use local storage I can give you the website its https://betl.gr when you are in the home page by clicking the logo on the nav bar it will change the website to dark mode and if you go to another page it will not work if you have something in mind on how to fix it I would be grateful

So I have found the problem because when the dark mode change the image change also on the homepage and when I’m on another page it gives value null does anyone knows how to fix it

You are missing an else statement, so if you are in light mode, the light mode logo does not get displayed when a new page loads. Other than that, your code works fine for me.
if (darkmode ==="active") enableDarkmode()
else disableDarkmode()  // EDIT Add this


The error occurred because the theme-switch functionality also updates an image on the homepage. Since the image is only present on the homepage, attempting to modify it on another page where it doesn't exist resulted in a null value being returned.
Here is the updated code:
// DarkMode
let darkmode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode")
const themeSwitch = document.getElementById("theme-switch")

const enableDarkmode = () => {
    document.body.classList.add("darkmode")
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", "active")
    // document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-white.png"
}

const disableDarkmode = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("darkmode")
    localStorage.setItem("darkmode", null)
    // document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-blue.png";
}

if (darkmode ==="active") enableDarkmode()

themeSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => {
    darkmode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode")

    darkmode !== "active" ? enableDarkmode() : disableDarkmode()
    darkmode === "active" ? document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-blue.png" : document.getElementById("logo").src="../Imgs/logo-white.png";
})

Thanks everyone for your time and sorry for wasting it
